# Why can I not drag and drop files in finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I have two finder windows open. One in an empty folder, and one a USB device with images on it (in list view). I have selected a bunch of images and when I click on them to drag and drop, nothing happens.

I am on Ventura 13.1 on a Macbook air with a trackpad.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is unclear where you say you click on the files, do you then drag them (or try) to the other Finder window? Finder will not show any activity on just a click, it must be a *click AND drag*

Comment: Is the USB drive formatted as NTFS by chance? macOS includes a read-only NTFS driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I couldn't drag anything in list view. I'd click, but when I dragged, the pointer would leave the item without bringing it along.

Just now, switching to Icons view let me drag things, and then when I switched back to List view I was able to drag there as well. We'll see if it sticks. For me this was on Ventura 13.4.